# Simple file upload to S3 using aws-sdk and Node/Express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multer-s3

I am at a loss of what I am doing wrong, here is what I have:

*HTML*

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="image">Image Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`Port` 5000 is my *Node.js* server's port.

In this example I am using `POST` to `/upload`, and it works fine.

```
module.exports = function(app, models) {

    var fs = require('fs');
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var accessKeyId =  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || "xxxxxx";
    var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || "+xxxxxx+B+xxxxxxx";

    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

        var params = {
            Bucket: 'makersquest',
            Key: 'myKey1234.png',
            Body: "Hello"
        };

        s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
            if (perr) {
                console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Now I want to post the file that I am `POST`ing, which is where the problem arises.

```
module.exports = function(app, models) {

    var fs = require('fs');
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var accessKeyId =  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || "xxxxxx";
    var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || "+xxxxxx+B+xxxxxxx";

    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        var path = req.files.image.path;
        fs.readFile(path, function(err, file_buffer){
            var params = {
                Bucket: 'makersquest',
                Key: 'myKey1234.png',
                Body: file_buffer
            };

            s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
                if (perr) {
                    console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
                } else {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

As a matter of fact `files` is completely empty.

I am assuming I am missing something pretty obvious but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: What version of node are you using? You can check with "node -v"

Answer (score 42):

### Simple S3 File Upload Without Multer

```
var express = require('express')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());


var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

app.post('/imageUpload', async (req, res) => {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "ACCESS-KEY", // Access key ID
        secretAccesskey: "SECRET-ACCESS-KEY", // Secret access key
        region: "us-east-1" //Region
    })


    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    // Binary data base64
    const fileContent  = Buffer.from(req.files.uploadedFileName.data, 'binary');

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'BUKET-NAME',
        Key: "test.jpg", // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: fileContent 
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.send({
            "response_code": 200,
            "response_message": "Success",
            "response_data": data
        });
    });

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Best answer because you use express-fileupload and native Buffer function

Comment: Agree, this is the best answer

Comment: Agreed this is my preferred answer.

Comment: how does one get the image back via a get request using this way, can you tell me in short

Comment: Agreed this is the best answer

Comment: I had problems with this because aws-sdk did not seem to be applying the credentials. I also notice the options you are using like `accessKeyId` are tagged as deprecated. However from the docs, I simply set the environment variables, and they are automatically applied: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html which then worked.

Answer (score 41):

You will need something like `multer` to handle multipart uploading.
Here is an example streaming your file upload to s3 using `aws-sdk`.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var accessKeyId =  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || "xxxxxx";
var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || "+xxxxxx+B+xxxxxxx";

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

app.use(multer({ // https://github.com/expressjs/multer
  dest: './public/uploads/', 
  limits : { fileSize:100000 },
  rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  },
  onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
    // file : { fieldname, originalname, name, encoding, mimetype, path, extension, size, truncated, buffer }
    var params = {
      Bucket: 'makersquest',
      Key: file.name,
      Body: data
    };

    s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
      if (perr) {
        console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
      }
    });
  }
}));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    if(req.files.image !== undefined){ // `image` is the field name from your form
        res.redirect("/uploads"); // success
    }else{
        res.send("error, no file chosen");
    }
});
```

Comment: In this example, Should I remove local file? such as `,
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
      fs.unlink(file.path)
    }`

Answer (score 35):

**[Update Mar 2022]** Supports **multiple file uploads** at a time, and returns the uploaded file(s)' public URL(s) too.

Latest Answer @ Dec-2016 **[New]**

Use [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) for multipart uploading to s3 without saving on local disk as:

```
var express = require('express'),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

var app = express(),
    s3 = new aws.S3();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
        }
    })
});

//open in browser to see upload form
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//use by upload form
app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl', 25), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({
        message: "Uploaded!",
        urls: req.files.map(function(file) {
            return {url: file.location, name: file.key, type: file.mimetype, size: file.size};
        })
    });
});
  
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Latest Answer @ Mar-2016 **[Old-One]**

**Edited 1** *use* `multer@1.1.0` *and* `multer-s3@1.4.1` *for following snippet*:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    s3 = require('multer-s3');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var upload = multer({
    storage: s3({
        dirname: '/',
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
        }
    })
});

//open in browser to see upload form
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//use by upload form
app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl'), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

For complete running example clone [express_multer_s3 repo](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3) and run `node app`.

Comment: getting errors with this code `default: throw new TypeError('Expected opts.s3 to be object')
             ^

TypeError: Expected opts.s3 to be object
    at new S3Storage (M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\node_modules\multer-s3\index.js:66:20)
    at module.exports (M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\node_modules\multer-s3\index.js:150:10)`

Comment: How do I know if the upload was success or not  and then redirect the screen based on that. Can you please show me how this is done. I am using `Multer-S3`

Comment: **Answer has been updated** @user2180794 hope both snippets work for you now

Comment: old but doesn't work for me (either of the 2). I get "Error: unexpected field".

Comment: @ManuelMaestrini did you follow the instructions properly or did you try it by cloning node-cheat?

Comment: I just followed the instructions and did .single as opposed to .array

Comment: i am using your code but this error is come "Expected opts.s3 to be object
"

Comment: @NallasamyNss you must be using inappropriate versions of npm modules, see this node-cheat link, see and install mentioned modules with correct version to make it work: 
https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/aws/express_multer_s3/app_es8.js

Comment: how does one get the image via get request using this method?

Comment: Currently multer-s3 3.0.1 has a severe security issue. https://github.com/anacronw/multer-s3/issues/188

Answer (score 1):

You need something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) in your set of middleware to handle `multipart/form-data` for you and populate `req.files`.  From the doco:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))
```

Now `req.files.image.path` should be populated in your `app.post` function.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy ways to upload your image is to use an NPM package [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
You can upload an image to `S3` and then store its name in your database so every time you want to fetch it you can generate a signed URL for that image. This is one of the ways to secure access to your `S3` bucket.

For uploading an image you can do something like this

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const cors = require("cors");
const {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 


const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Read the values from .env file

const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const bucketRegion = process.env.BUCKET_REGION;
const accessId = process.env.ACCESS_ID;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

// Create a client

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: accessId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  },
  region: bucketRegion,
});

// This function generates unique name for our files 

const generateFileName = (bytes = 32) =>
  crypto.randomBytes(bytes).toString("hex");
  
// Notice the upload middleware.
// "image" is the same name that you will pass form your UI request

app.post('/', upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  
  # When you use multer the image can be accessed from req.file

    let fileName = generateFileName()
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key:  fileName,
        Body: req.file.buffer ,
        ContentType: req.file.mimetype,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    await s3.send(command);

// before sending response you can save the 'fileName' in the DB of your choice
      
    res.send('image uploaded')
  
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Next, to get the signed URL for the image you can do as follows

```js
// assuming other things are set as above snippet 
const { GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 // First you will get the image name that was saved in DB
 // lets say it was called user_image. 
 
   let obj_params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: user_image,
    };
    
    let command = new GetObjectCommand(obj_params);
    image_url = await getSignedUrl(
      s3,
      command,
      { expiresIn: 86400 } // seconds in a day
    );
    
    let response = {
      success: true, 
      data: {
        image_url
      },
    };
    res.status(200).send(response); 
})
```

> Note:
>
> - Note that you might need to install some packages to make it work.
> - Make sure in your API requests you are setting `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` in request headers
> - In your API gateway in `S3`, you might also need to set the `Binary Media Type` as `multipart/form-data`. More info on that in [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)

Answer (score 0):

This stack overflow was the best answer I found explaining exactly how to get Node to S3 working.

[AWS Missing credentials when i try send something to my S3 Bucket (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284181/aws-missing-credentials-when-i-try-send-something-to-my-s3-bucket-node-js)

This in addition to some more stuff I had to hack on to get it all working. In my situation I was using a MEAN stack application so my Node file I was working with was a route file.

my aconfig.json file with the amazon credentials looks like this:

```
{ "accessKeyId": "*****YourAccessKey****", "secretAccessKey": "***YourSecretKey****" }
```

The final contents of the route file look like the file pasted below.

```
router.post('/sendToS3', function(req, res) {

var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');

var awsCredFile = path.join(__dirname, '.', 'aconfig.json');

console.log('awsCredFile is');
console.log(awsCredFile);

AWS.config.loadFromPath(awsCredFile);

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var photoBucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myGreatBucketName'}});

var sampleFile = {
    "_id" : 345345,
    "fieldname" : "uploads[]",
    "originalname" : "IMG_1030.JPG",
    "encoding" : "7bit",
    "mimetype" : "image/jpeg",
    "destination" : "./public/images/uploads",
    "filename" : "31a66c51883595e74ab7ae5e66fb2ab8",
    "path" : "/images/uploads/31a66c51883595e74ab7ae5e66fb2ab8",
    "size" : 251556,
    "user" : "579fbe61adac4a8a73b6f508"
};

var filePathToSend = path.join(__dirname, '../public', sampleFile.path);


function uploadToS3(filepath, destFileName, callback) {
    photoBucket
        .upload({
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
            Key: destFileName.toString(),
            ContentType: 'application/octet-stream' // force download if it's accessed as a top location
        })
        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#httpUploadProgress-event
        .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })
        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#send-property
        .send(callback);
}

multer({limits: {fileSize:10*1024*1024}});

console.log('filePathToSend is ');
console.log(filePathToSend);

uploadToS3(filePathToSend, sampleFile.filename, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('failed to upload to s3').end();
    }
    res.status(200)
        .send('File uploaded to S3: '
            + data.Location.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            + '<br/><img src="' + data.Location.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"/>')
        .end();
});

console.log('uploading now...');

});
```

This took me a while to finally get working, but if you setup the route below, update the sampleFile JSON to point to a real file on your system and hit it with Postman it will publish a file to your S3 account.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please do not hesitate to describe the answer even though the link leads to the detailed view of it.