# Upload to S3 using aws-sdk and Node/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, multer

I've been following this guide [Simple file upload to S3 using aws-sdk and Node/Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930204/simple-file-upload-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-and-node-express/19694847)  to attempt to let users upload images via S3. For some reason I cannot get it to work. How would I fix my code to correct the error?

The error I get is: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

```
    var aws             = require('aws-sdk');
    var multerS3        = require('multer-s3');
    var  multer          = require("multer");

    (Not real codes)
    aws.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: 'QWUdawup',
        accessKeyId: 'GHQWD1A',
        region: 'us-east-2'
    });

       var s3 = new aws.S3();

    var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: 'medstayfiles',
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                console.log(file);
                cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
            }
        })
    });



router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.array('image', 1), function(req, res,next){

        var filepath = undefined;
        if(req.files[0]) {
            filepath = req.files[0].key; // 'uploads/xxxxx.extension'
        }

        var newRentals = {filepath: filepath}

        Rentals.create(newRentals, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //redirect back to rentals page
                res.redirect("/rentals");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your router config? What is middleware.isLoggedin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention where the error was appearing, but based on your code, it seems that `req.files` is undefined.  You probably need to add the appropriate middleware for handling file uploads.

Really though, if you're accepting posts from web users, you should just have them upload to S3 directly using a pre-signed URL or upload form.  Save yourself the hassle and the bandwidth.

Comment: that's nice. do you have any example on how to do that?