# How do I host static files on AWS S3 using next?

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, next.js

I'm coming from Django background where static files are mostly stored on S3, I'm trying to understand how it works on NodeJS since I'd like to migrate an app from Django/React to NodeJS/NextJS/ExpressJS/React.

I don't get how & where to store my static files (client side js, css, images) on a production environment? I think to know [how to upload to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930204/simple-file-upload-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-and-node-express) and manage **dynamic** files since the work is done by the users through the express api, but I'm searching for something where I can batch upload all the public files to s3 on deploy (is this even the right way to do with express?).

Since I'd like to deploy to Heroku I know that they have a policy of not keeping those static files, (In Django I use "collectstatic" command to batch upload all my static files to S3 on each deploy), how & from where do you serve those files in here?

Any advice would help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is.  You say you know how to upload stuff to S3, but you're asking how to upload stuff to S3?  Or, are you looking for something like collectstatic?

Comment: @Brad There's a difference between dynamic and static files, I'm searching for something like 'collectstatic' where every file in a folder uploads to s3 on deploy. I'm wondering if it's right way to do so?

Comment: Usually, I just write a little deployment script which uses `s3cmd` to do the uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**next.config.js**, set [assetPrefix](https://nextjs.org/docs#cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) to your aws s3 link in production.

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const version = require('./package.json').version;

assetPrefix: isDev ? '' : `https://${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${version}`,
```

**collectstatic.js**, run on postbuild release.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const readDir = require('recursive-readdir');
const path = require('path');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const mime = require('mime-types');
const version = require('./package.json').version;

// You will run this script from your CI/Pipeline after build has completed.
// It will read the content of the build directory and upload to S3 (live assets bucket)
// Every deployment is immutable. Cache will be invalidated every time you deploy.
AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY,
  maxRetries: 3
});

// Retrive al the files path in the build directory
const getDirectoryFilesRecursive = (dir, ignores = []) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readDir(dir, ignores, (err, files) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(files)));
  });
};

// The Key will look like this: _next/public/<buildid>/pages/index.js
// the <buildid> is exposed by nextJS and it's unique per deployment.
// See: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-7/#static-cdn-support
const generateFileKey = (fileName, toReplace, replaced) => {
  // I'm interested in only the last part of the file: '/some/path/.next/build-manifest.json',
  const S3objectPath = fileName.split(toReplace)[1];
  return version + replaced + S3objectPath;
};

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const uploadToS3 = async (fileArray, toReplace, replaced) => {
  try {
    fileArray.map(file => {
      // Configuring parameters for S3 Object
      const S3params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(file),
        Key: generateFileKey(file, toReplace, replaced),
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: String(mime.lookup(file)),
        ContentEncoding: 'utf-8',
        CacheControl: 'immutable,max-age=31536000,public'
      };

      s3.upload(S3params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          // Set the exit code while letting
          // the process exit gracefully.
          console.error(err);
          process.exitCode = 1;
        } else {
          console.log(`Assets uploaded to S3:`, data.key);
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// Start function
// getDirectoryFilesRecursive(path, ignore);
const start = async function(dict) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
    const files = await getDirectoryFilesRecursive(path.resolve(__dirname, dict[i].filePath), ['.DS_Store', 'BUILD_ID']);
    uploadToS3(files, dict[i].toReplace, dict[i].replaced);
  }
}

// Call start
start([
  {
    filePath: '.next',
    toReplace: '.next/',
    replaced: '/_next/'
  }
]);
```

Run `node collectstatic.js` to upload all your assets to S3.

Comment: what about iss ? where will be new static generated runtime data stored , they will not be stored in s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

What is your source for Heroku has "a policy of not keeping those static files"?

It is true that if you want to add functionality of image uploads to your app, then a solution like S3 could be helpful, seeing as Heroku uses dynos (Isolated Linux Processes) that don't allow for dynamically writing to the filesystem.

Other than that use case ("users should be able to upload files"), using S3 for static files seems like an unnecessary complexity.

The NodeJS API for serving static files is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

To experiment with this API on Heroku, I would deploy this [barebones sample NodeJS/Express/React App](https://github.com/ElishaKay/ReactJS-Book-Library) using NodeJS's static files API.

The repo uses npm's `react-scripts` library to bundle and compile the React code, and the server simply serves the files bundled into the dynamically generated `'/build'` folder.

Hence your server code becomes as simple as:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
const port = process.env.PORT || '8080';
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

If you really want S3 running with Node and Express I would checkout:
[This StackOverflow Thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930204/simple-file-upload-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-and-node-express)