# React app will not upload image to aws S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I have a React app that I'm trying to configure to enable users to upload images via a post form.  The form has other fields in it.

The back end is here: https://github.com/JohnTarvis/a2backend
The front end is here: https://github.com/JohnTarvis/a2frontend

The site is hosted here: https://anonsanonymous.netlify.app/

I'm attempting to incorporate code from this thread:[Simple file upload to S3 using aws-sdk and Node/Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930204/simple-file-upload-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-and-node-express/35902286)

specifically this:

```
const express = require('express'); //"^4.13.4"
const aws = require('aws-sdk'); //"^2.2.41"
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer'); // "^1.3.0"
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3'); //"^2.7.0"

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY',
    accessKeyId: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

const app = express();
const s3 = new aws.S3();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
        }
    })
});

//open http://localhost:3000/ in browser to see upload form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//used by upload form
app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl',1), (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

And I have something like this in my back end using router.js instead of app.js

```
router.post("/",upload.array('upload',1), async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const validator = jsonschema.validate(req.body, postNewSchema);
    if (!validator.valid) {
      const errs = validator.errors.map(e => e.stack);
      throw new BadRequestError(errs);
    }
    
    const newPost = await Post.create(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({ newPost });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

This is in my upload form on the front end:

```
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Upload File</label>
                  <input 
                    type="file" 
                    name="upload"
                    value={formData.image}
                    onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  />
                </div>
```

The post appears but the image does not upload.  I'm thinking it could be a problem communicating the file between my front end and back end.  The basic app that I copied from here uploads to my S3 but not the main one I'm working on.  Is it my upload form or my express back end that is having the problem?  I only posted part of my code cause it's several dozen files but if you need to see more, I'll add it.

Comment: Are you able to receive files in the Backend successfully?

Comment: Have you set up the permissions for putting objects in s3?

Comment: @TristanMüller Yes

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara There's the rub.  For some reason when I console log something from an axios request it won't show up in the Heroku console.  I'm going to try other ways of testing but I suspect this may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0: Log in to your aws console. Search for Amazon S3 and click on Create bucket.
Step 1: bootstrap react. you need to create our react app.
Step 2: Import react-aws-s3.
Step 3: Set up file structure.
Step 4: Adding environment variables to .
Step 5: Setting up our Upload component.
Step 6: Grabbing the file.
Step 7: Updating AWS S3 CORS.
Step 6: Implementing the upload functionality.

I'm still new to react  but i hope i can help ,goodluck! :)

Comment: Yep, I did all of that.